# How to use different php.ini files for different VirtualHosts?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have my site and it's staging subdomain running on the same CentOS machine running apache. The subdomain is created using a VirtualHost, and I use it to find any bugs before I push to production. I want the php.ini file for the staging VirtualHost to be a development one, and the production site will use a production php.ini. How can I configure apache to use different php.ini files? I don't want to use php_value/php_flag for everything, I'd rather just use the php.ini file I already have available. I've tried creating an .htaccess file that looks like this,

```
SetEnv PHPRC /path/to/php.ini/directory
```

This has no effect, as phpinfo() tells me it's still using /etc/php.ini. I've also tried setting PHPIniDir for both virtual hosts (www and staging) and it complains about seeing the directive twice.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `PHPIniDir` for just the staging and leaving the production side as the default?

Comment: You might also check this [question/answers](http://serverfault.com/questions/34078/how-do-i-set-up-per-site-php-ini-files-on-a-lamp-server-using-namevirtualhosts).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **it is impossible** to specify different php.ini files for each virtual host.

However you can change *almost anything* in the php.ini file by using the [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function:

- It allows you to set the value of a given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.
- Not all the available options can be changed using [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). There is a list of all available options [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php). Thus, all directives having the "PHP_INI_USER" mode can be changed during runtime by using the [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.